# laravel 8 passing data to redirect url

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i have store function for save data to database and i want redirect to another url with passing $invoice variable

this is my store function :

```
 $order = Order::create([
        'no' => $invoice,
        'spg' => $request->spg,
        'nama' => $request->nama,
        'hp' => $request->hp,
        'alamat' => $request->alamat,
    ]);
 return redirect('invoicelink', compact('invoice'));
```

this is my route file:

```
Route::resource('/', OrderController::class);
Route::get('invoicelink/{invoice}', [OrderController::class, 'invoicelink'])->name('invoicelink');
```

and this is my invoicelink function:

```
public function invoicelink($invoice)
    {
        dd($invoice);
    }
```

How to do it? very grateful if someone help to solve my problem. thanks

Comment: but you didn't define the `$invoice` variable

Comment: im newb where should I define it ? and can you explain it for study purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution:

web.php

```
Route::get('invoicelink/{invoice}', [OrderController::class, 'invoicelink'])->name('invoicelink');
```

controller:

```
public function invoicelink($invoice)
{
    //dd($invoice);
    return $invoice;
}
```

then use redirect:

```
return redirect()->route('invoicelink', [$invoice]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the helper function you are calling, I don't think it is what you are looking for.

```
function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
{
    if (is_null($to)) {
        return app('redirect');
    }

    return app('redirect')->to($to, $status, $headers, $secure);
}
```

I think what you want is

```
Redirect::route('invoiceLink', $invoice);
```

You can also use the redirect function, but it would look like this

```
redirect()->route('invoiceLink', $invoice);
```

You can see this documented here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-named-routes